# CSS - Centering a page - then making the page 100% height

Tags: css

I'm trying to center a page and then make it `100%` in height.
I have a div called "content" as the parent element of all elements in the HTML page.
What do I need to do next? I'd like to stay away from any CSS-hacks.
This is currently working in IE7, but not in Firefox 3.

**EDIT:** I added height: `100%`; to `#content` that's what made it work in IE. Firefox still not solved.

My stylesheet so far is:

```
html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center; 
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
} 

#content
{
    position: relative; 
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 840px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: I can see nothing wrong in my FF 3.0. Could you give more details ?

Answer (score 4):

To center content, put it inside of an element that has a fixed width (important!) and has `margin: auto;`

There is no cross-browser was to make your div have 100% height unless you use javascript. If you are desperate for this functionality and are willing to use javascript, you can dynamically set the height of your content by setting it to the window height. I've never done this so I won't tell you how exactly, but it should be easy to find by googling.

Comment: I got the centering thing figured out. Just can't figure out the height thing now. I think I am leaning towards the JavaScript solution (thought about that on the drive in to work today).

Answer (score 2):

Ahah! Think I got it for now. This works in Firefox 3 and IE7. I will test on some other browsers later. I do still need to figure out adding some padding around my content.

This requires this heirarchy on my page

```
html  
|__body  
     |__div id=container  
         |__div id=content
```

```
    html
    {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body
    {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #container
    {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center; 
        background-color: #000;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;    
    } 

    #content
    {
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 830px; /* padding thing I'm working on */
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body
{
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center; 
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
} 

#content
{
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Try this. This will work. Remove the html,body selector, you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Firefox 3 & Safari 3. Don't have access to IE.

```
html{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:-1px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
body{
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:0;
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:30em;
  max-width:50em;
  width:expression("40em");/*IE doesn't support max/min width*/
  padding:0 1em 0 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it better.
No extra markup and/or id.
No need for javascript and/or expression in css.
Should work fine on all browsers.

```
<style>

html 
{
 background-color:red; 
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:0px;       
}

body{
 background-color:yellow;
 position:absolute;
 left:-400px; /* 50% of content width */
 width:800px; /* your content width */
 margin-left:50%;
 margin-top:0;
 margin-bottom:0;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 border:0;
 padding:0
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

For centering the page, I typically just put the content div in the center tag, because margin-left/right:auto really doesn't work in all versions of IE.

For making the page the whole height, you can fake it a couple of ways.  My favorite is to create a background image for the body tag that is centered horizontally but tiles vertically, so that would give the main div its white background.  You probably still have a footer though, so you can position it with bottom:0 and that should keep it at the bottom and give you a content div which appears to extend for the whole page.

Comment: Minus 1 for the first paragraph (avoid using center tag), but the second paragraph is a good idea - let the #content div stretch or contract all it wants, but use a repeating background image on the body to make it appear 100% all the time.

So, I'll say +1 overall.